# can not find M-x python-nav-beginning-of-defun

Tags: python, emacs, key-bindings

I am using Emacs on Windows, using evil mode for my keybindings.

I want to set a keybinding for going back to the first line of a function's definition.

I found a reference to <kbd>M-x</kbd> `python-nav-end-of-defun`. But strangely, I can't find `python-nav-beginning-of-defun`.

How can I find this function so I can bind it?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `end-of-defun` and `beginning-of-defun` per usual, since they call the `python-nav-*-defun` functions (bound locally in `python-mode`).  You probably can't find `python-nav-beginning-of-defun` because it is not an interactive function -- it is designed to be called by `beginning-of-defun` -- although if you used <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `python-nav-beginning-of-defun` you would find its help documentation.

I don't know how evil binds these, but in normal emacs they would typically be <kbd>C-M-a</kbd> and <kbd>C-M-e</kbd> respectively.

Comment: you are master ty

Comment: any way, why python-nav-beginning-of-defun , i can not find it ?

Comment: you should be able to with `M-x describe-function` `python-nav-beginning-of-defun` (after `python.el` has been loaded)